XBRL validation error: xbrldie:PrimaryItemDimensionallyInvalidError
Based on taxonomy I have I try to present answers in following table structure:

Based on my current understanding (which may be wrong as I am relatively new to xbrl) I build XBRL instance:
    <xbrli:context id="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_ShortTermMember">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="y2024">2024</xbrli:identifier>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2024-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2024-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
        <xbrli:scenario>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="ifrs-sds:TimeHorizonAxis">
                ifrs-sds:ShortTermMember
            </xbrldi:explicitMember>
        </xbrli:scenario>
    </xbrli:context>

    <ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_ShortTermMember">
        Your explanatory text here for short term member...
    </ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory>

But it fails during validation with an error:
[xbrldie:PrimaryItemDimensionallyInvalidError] Fact ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory context y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon dimensionally not valid

If I remove xbrli:scenario tag and its children validation pass. But, how I can I give different definition of time horizon for every member if I cannot use them? What am I doing wrong here?

Current xbrl instance:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xbrli:xbrl
    xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
    xmlns:xbrldi="http://www.xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"
    xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
    xmlns:ifrs-sds="https://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2024-04-26/ifrs-sds"
    xmlns:ifrs-ibg="https://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2024-04-26/ifrs-ibg"
    xmlns:dtr-2022="http://www.example.org/dtr-2022"
>
    <link:schemaRef
        xlink:type="simple"
        xlink:href="https://ifrs-taxonomy-ya2zds.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/ifrs_sds_2024-04-26.xsd"
    />
    <xbrli:context id="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_ShortTermMember">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="y2024">y2024</xbrli:identifier>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2024-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2024-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
        <xbrli:scenario>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="ifrs-sds:TimeHorizonAxis">
                ifrs-sds:ShortTermMember
            </xbrldi:explicitMember>
        </xbrli:scenario>
    </xbrli:context>

    <xbrli:context id="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_MediumTermMember">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="y2024">2024</xbrli:identifier>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2024-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2024-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
        <xbrli:scenario>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="ifrs-sds:TimeHorizonAxis">
                ifrs-sds:MediumTermMember
            </xbrldi:explicitMember>
        </xbrli:scenario>
    </xbrli:context>

    <xbrli:context id="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_LongTermMember">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="y2024">2024</xbrli:identifier>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2024-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2024-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
        <xbrli:scenario>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="ifrs-sds:TimeHorizonAxis">
                ifrs-sds:LongTermMember
            </xbrldi:explicitMember>
        </xbrli:scenario>
    </xbrli:context>

    <ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory
        contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_ShortTermMember"
    >
        Your explanatory text here for short term member...
    </ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory>

    <ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory
        contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_MediumTermMember"
    >
        Your explanatory text here for medium term member...
    </ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory>

    <ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory
        contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_LongTermMember"
    >
        Your explanatory text here for long term member...
    </ifrs-sds:DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory>

    <ifrs-sds:HowDefinitionOfTimeHorizonsIsLinkedToPlanningHorizonsUsedForStrategicDecisionmakingExplanatory
        contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_ShortTermMember"
    >
        Your explanatory text here for short term member...
    </ifrs-sds:HowDefinitionOfTimeHorizonsIsLinkedToPlanningHorizonsUsedForStrategicDecisionmakingExplanatory>

    <ifrs-sds:HowDefinitionOfTimeHorizonsIsLinkedToPlanningHorizonsUsedForStrategicDecisionmakingExplanatory
        contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_MediumTermMember"
    >
        Your explanatory text here for medium term member...
    </ifrs-sds:HowDefinitionOfTimeHorizonsIsLinkedToPlanningHorizonsUsedForStrategicDecisionmakingExplanatory>

    <ifrs-sds:HowDefinitionOfTimeHorizonsIsLinkedToPlanningHorizonsUsedForStrategicDecisionmakingExplanatory
        contextRef="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_LongTermMember"
    >
        Your explanatory text here for long term member...
    </ifrs-sds:HowDefinitionOfTimeHorizonsIsLinkedToPlanningHorizonsUsedForStrategicDecisionmakingExplanatory>

</xbrli:xbrl>


I also tried different layout inside context element, but with this new layout I just got different error:
    <xbrli:context id="y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_LongTermMember">
        <xbrli:entity>
            <xbrli:identifier scheme="y2024">2024</xbrli:identifier>
            <xbrli:segment>
                <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="ifrs-sds:TimeHorizonAxis">
                    ifrs-sds:LongTermMember
                </xbrldi:explicitMember>
            </xbrli:segment>
        </xbrli:entity>
        <xbrli:period>
            <xbrli:startDate>2024-01-01</xbrli:startDate>
            <xbrli:endDate>2024-12-31</xbrli:endDate>
        </xbrli:period>
    </xbrli:context>

[xbrlxe:nonDimensionalSegmentScenarioContent] Contexts MUST not contain non-dimensional content: y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory_LongTermMember - disclosure-v6.xbrl 25, 40


A possibility that comes to mind is that the hypercube may be defined on xbrli:segment instead of xbrli:scenario. This is not visible on the screenshot, but if you open the definition linkbase XML file and search for xbrldt:contextElement, and if it says "segment", then this would be the explanation.
Getting this error is nevertheless partially informative, because it confirms that the concept DefinitionOfTimeHorizonExplanatory (which I assume corresponds to the text block in the screenshot) is correctly tied to a hypercube. Only correctly attached concepts can be dimensionally invalid.

@GhislainFourny thank you for your thoughts,
I am using this taxonomy https://www.ifrs.org/content/dam/ifrs/standards/sustainability-disclosure-taxonomy/2024/ifrssdt-2024-04-26.zip
I checked for the xbrldt:contextElement as you suggested, but in my case there are only scenarios.

Do you have any other thoughts on what might be worth checking?

In addition when I open Arelle GUI and tried to valided file there fot another error that is not presetned in CLI: [xbrlxe:nonDimensionalSegmentScenarioContent] Contexts MUST not contain non-dimensional content: y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_LongTermMember, y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_MediumTermMember, y2024_DefinitionOfTimeHorizon_ShortTermMember - disclosure-v4.xbrl 18, 34, 49

Thank you @Kishieel. Would it be possible to see the entire .xbrl instance file? Then I could test it locally.

@GhislainFourny sure, I added what I have to the question

Thank you for providing the full document.
The namespace for xbrldi seems incorrect, it should be http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi without the www..
The reason why the incorrect namespace leads to a higher-level error rather than an XML validation error (which would have been more informative) is that in the lower layer of XBRL, there can be any content inside segments and scenarios, even with unknown namespaces. XBRL Dimensions adds a layer that requires specific elements such as xbrldi:explicitMember (in the http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi namespace).
Whether segment or scenario should be used differs by jurisdiction, and is specified in the taxonomy as discussed in the comments. In the US (EDGAR) segments are commonly used. In the EU (ESEF) scenarios are commonly used.
Generally, the correctness of namespaces can be checked by adding a hint for schema validation with an xsi:schemaLocation attribute containing an alternating list of namespaces and schema locations. The check for validity against the schemas can be done with an independent XML processor (although it will not perform any XBRL-related checks, only XML schema validity checks) or with an XBRL processor (which typically contains a validating XML processor).
<xbrli:xbrl
  xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"
  xmlns:xbrldi="http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi"
  xmlns:link="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:iso4217="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217"
  xmlns:ifrs-sds="https://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2024-04-26/ifrs-sds"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance
    https://www.xbrl.org/2003/2003-12-31/xbrl-instance-2003-12-31.xsd
    http://xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi
    http://www.xbrl.org/2006/xbrldi-2006.xsd
    http://www.xbrl.org/2003/linkbase
    https://www.xbrl.org/2003/xbrl-linkbase-2003-12-31.xsd
    http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
    https://www.w3.org/XML/2008/06/xlink.xsd
    http://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217
    https://www.xbrl.org/2003/iso4217-2003-05-16.xsd
    https://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/2024-04-26/ifrs-sds
    https://xbrl.ifrs.org/taxonomy/ifrs_sds/2024-04-26/ifrs_sds/ifrs_sds-cor_2024-04-26.xsd
    "
>

A few more hints:

Two namespaces are unused (ifrs-ibg and dtr-2022) so I omitted them.
The default namespace was also unused and I omitted it (it is not recommended to use a default namespace in the presence of multiple namespaces).
Regarding ifrs-sds, it is better practice to use the official location rather than a copy. XBRL engines are normally supposed to automate caching them and/or reading from taxonomy packages.


Thank you very much, it passes validation now. What about other namspaces like xmlns="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance" or xmlns:xbrli="http://www.xbrl.org/2003/instance"? Or it only applies to this one? How can I confirm that may other namesapces are correct?

You are welcome! The other namespaces look correct, except dtr-2022, but it seems not used and can be removed. I have expanded the response with an explanation on how to trigger the validation of elements in namespaces.
